# Which direction to open the Paroches on the Aron Kodesh

Tags: synagogue, ark-aron-kodesh

Inspired by DanF question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83446/why-does-the-bride-circle-the-groom-in-a-counter-clockwise-direction). Covering the Aron Kodesh in a Shul is a curtain called the Paroches. One needs to open up the curtain before taking out the Torah. Which direction is one supposed to open the curtain - from right to left or left to right? I have seen both ways done in Shuls. Can someone bring sources for opening in either direction?

Comment: I'd say right to left like the Hebrew reading direction...And "chesed-gevurah." But I have no source.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with interpreting going from right to left. Does it mean start from the right or does it mean to go in the direction of the right. The latter would mean one starts from the left.

Comment: I would think you would start with right, similar to the way we put on shoes.

Comment: I'd think it has mostly to do with the construction of the curtain(s) and door(s). Some allow easy access by only one direction of opening the curtains.

Comment: In the second Mikdash according to Rabbi Yehuda, there was a double parochey, the firse was open on the south side, the cohen g was walking between the two in north   directin and the second was opened on the north edge. I remember approximately, see 5th chapter of Yoma in Gemara

Comment: Very interesting question. Many shuls have the "parochet" attached to the doors. My shul has a main (Shabbat / Yom Tov) shul as well as a smaller "weekday" shul. The smaller shul's Aron has a parochet as well as "French" doors (i.e., 2 doors that open outward away from the Aron. I will ask a related question, soon.  In some shuls, the parochet is "attached" to the door. (cont.)

Comment: The upstairs shul has just that, and it's a sliding door. No choice here. You have to slide it from right to left.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83459/5275

Comment: @ezra Are you implying that a lefty should open the paroches the other way?

Comment: and the second parochet is opened from right! so perhaps the minhag came from this

Answer (score 2):

Rabi Ovadia Yosef ZATSAL.

(so his son said - Rabi Avraham Yosef so i heard him and here is a [link](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=110430) to his answer)

And Rabi Meir  Mazuz  SHLITa

(so i heard him and here is a [link](https://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/5180) answered in his Yeshiva).

Both saying from the left side to the right. 
So if you are looking forward to the Aron Kodesh, you are taking your right hand to your left and pushing the PAROCHET to the right. 
That way you are committing :
"all your turns will be to the right"
HAZAK.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the parochet. The schul I grew up in has a parochet which goes towards the right, whereas the one I daven by now has one which goes towards the left. The former is a Chabad, the latter a fairly mainstream Orthodox minyan. Further, many older, Western European schuls (such as Ohel Avraham in Paris and Orach Chaim in NYC) have parochot which open from the centre.

Answer (score 1):

According to *Shut Be'er Moshe* ([5:38](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=889&st=&pgnum=53)), there is no definitive way it should be opened, and whichever way one opens it is fine.