# If a Torah ark has "French" doors, which door should be opened first?

Tags: synagogue, torah-service, ark-aron-kodesh, opening-the-ark

Extending [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83450/5275):

Some shuls, such as mine, have "French" doors on the Aron. These are two vertical doors that open "outwards" (i.e., towards you when facing the Aron. Well, if it opened inwards, it would smack into the *Sifrei Torah*, I presume.)

When someone opens the Aron, which door should he open first - left or right? Or should he open both at the same time?

If the Torah that's needed is behind a specific door, can he just open a single door that's in front of the Torah and leave the other one closed?

Comment: At my shul we open both at the same time. However, we also have a curtain behind the doors.

Comment: In my Yeshiva the Torah is behind the right door, and whether only that one is opened or both seems to be the poseach's preference.

Comment: May I ask why this isn't a dupe of the question you linked? Why do you think that one might open the doors from right to left but the curtain left to right?

Comment: @DonielF There's a slightly different direction involved when dealing with French doors then with a curtain. The curtain moves in a straight line perpendicular to the opening of the Aron. French doors rotate and swing outwards towards the one opening it. When the doors are closed they are parallel to the Aron, but when opened, they are perpendicular.